# CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX not added to CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH after setting CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME to Generic

Tags: windows, cmake

I am cross-compiling a project with CMake. `find_library` fails to find a library that is located in `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib`, because `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is not being appended to `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH` as it should according to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html).

The cause for this is that I set `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to `Generic` in my toolchain file. I stripped down the toolchain file to this single command. Why does it affect the behaviour of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`?

If I set `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to `Linux` or `Windows`, `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH` has some preset and also `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is appended as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the documentation is wrong here. Adding `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH` is not done automatically. This is done inside CMake modules that are specific to the Windows and Linux platforms (e.g. c:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.14\Modules\Platform\WindowsPaths.cmake on my computer).

To mimic the same behaviour for non-Windows and non-Linux platforms, you can do the following. In the toolchain file, define a unique system name and also add the current directory to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` so that Cmake will look for modules here:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME "MySystem")
list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

Then create a platform file called `<CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME>.cmake` in a sub-folder called `Platform` (e.g. `Platform\MySystem.cmake`). Inside this file you can append `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH`:

```
# Copied from c:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.14\Modules\Platform\WindowsPaths.cmake 
if (NOT CMAKE_FIND_NO_INSTALL_PREFIX)
  list(APPEND CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH
    # Project install destination.
    "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}"
  )
  if(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX)
    list(APPEND CMAKE_SYSTEM_PREFIX_PATH
      # User-supplied staging prefix.
      "${CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX}"
    )
  endif()
endif()
```